# GWAS QQPlot with -log10(p) distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a QQPlot of 100 log-transformed p values from a GWAS study. The idea is that taking the -log(p) will magnify the smallest p values to make them easier to see. ([reference](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Code_Sample:_Generating_QQ_Plots_in_R))

I was able to do it easily in ggplot2 in base e, but my PI wants to see it in base 10. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a built-in quantile function for base 10, so I wrote one by hand (modified from the code in [reference](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Code_Sample:_Generating_QQ_Plots_in_R)).

However, the graphs do not look exactly the same so I am wondering if I did it correctly. If anyone could let me know if my code makes sense or if there is a better way, I would really appreciate it!

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Simulate 100 p values drawn from a uniform distribution
p.values <- tibble(p = runif(100))

# QQPlot with base e
ggplot(p.values, aes(sample = -log(p))) +
  stat_qq(distribution = qexp) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Theoretical quantile function for -log10(p)
qlog10 <- function(p.values) {
  theoretical <- rank(p.values)/length(p.values)
  return(-log10(theoretical))
}

# QQplot with base 10
ggplot(p.values, aes(x = qlog10(p), y = -log10(p))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes you did it fine. The difference is the factor of log(10). You can recreate your first plot in -log10(p) space, but change geom_qq(qexp, dparams=list(rate=log(10))).